# Turn off Always Prompt For Logon Credentials in Outlook 2007 using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook, credentials, prompt, authentication

Is it possible to turn off "Always Prompt For Logon Credentials" in Outlook 2007 using vbscript?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to override domain policy?  Just curious why you don't just untick the box.

Comment: We are migrating machines remotely to a different domain, and currently they have this box checked. They are already using the new domain's exchange email.

Comment: I guess a couple of pointers .. Gpo settings may do this .. also it could be in the registry and then you could write some vbs to change it. best way to find out is to use a sys internals tool called Regmon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx with monitors the registry while you deselect the check box .. and you see th key change..

Comment: Thanks, BTW Regmon has been replaced by Process Monitor.  I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the following article and it solved my issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940171

HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Security\PromptForCredentials

DWORD set to 0

Thanks to 76mel for the tip.